# Simple bibliography error

Tags: bibliographies

I use this code and there is an error when I always refer to a webpage which contains _, and it says me missing $ inserted. How could I cancel this problem?

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{Introduction to CFT} 
Blumenhagen, R., Plauschinn, E., Introduction to Conformal Field Theory: With Applications
to String Theory, Lect. Notes Phys. 779 (Springer, Berlin Heidelberg 2009), DOI 10.1007
978-3-642-00450-6
\\\texttt{http://stringworld.ru/files/Blumenhagen_R._Plauschinn_E._Introduction_to_conformal_field_theory_with_applications_to_string_theory.pdf}`

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: `_` should be `\_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't encase the URL in a `\texttt` directive. Instead, be sure to load the [url](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/url/) package, possibly with the option `hyphens`, and then write `\url{<long url string here>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}      

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{Introduction to CFT} 
Blumenhagen, R., Plauschinn, E., Introduction to Conformal Field Theory: 
With Applications to String Theory, Lect.\ Notes Phys.\ 779 (Springer, 
Berlin and Heidelberg 2009), DOI 10.1007, ISBN 978-3-642-00450-6\linebreak 
\url{http://stringworld.ru/files/Blumenhagen_R._Plauschinn_E._Introduction_to_conformal_field_theory_with_applications_to_string_theory.pdf}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```